# Bubble sort in HCS12/9s12 cpu is giving no memory at error

Tags: assembly

I am using CodeWorrior to write Bubble sort for 9S12 cpu.

I have written  the below code and its swapping correctly all the bytes but when i run the code its giving me No memory error at [521:1] i have to press F5 again and again to run till end.

```
MY_EXTENDED_RAM: SECTION
; Insert here your data definition. For demonstration, temp_byte is used.
;temp_byte:  DS.B   1

flag:  DS.B   1
output_data: DS.B 32
output_data_end:

; code section
MyCode:     SECTION
; this assembly routine is called by the C/C++ application
asm_main:



            ldx #input_data
            ldy #output_data
back:       ldaa 0,x
            staa 0,y
            inx
            iny
            cpx #input_data_end
            bne back
next_pass:  ldaa #$0
            staa flag
            ldx  #output_data    ;Load the X register with the start of the output_data buffer using its label 
next:       ldaa 0,x
            cmpa 1,x 
            blt  notnow
            ldab 1,x
            stab 0,x
            staa 1,x
            ldaa #$1
            staa flag
notnow:     inx
            cpx #output_data_end 
            bne next
            tst flag
            bne next_pass

            swi                   

input_data:  dc.b $15, $C7, $18, $15, $A0, $21, $23, $D5, $27, $0A, $C5, $C8, $A2, $CC, $AB, $A2
             dc.b $A5, $A8, $D2, $13, $17, $B3, $C4, $14, $AA, $AD, $15, $AE, $A2, $A5, $C1, $C2 

input_data_end:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one error in your code. Your `output_data` array has 32 elements but only 31 consecutive pairs of elements. Your inner loop compares 32 pairs of elements, starting with offsets 0 and 1 and ending at offsets 31 and 32. That last comparison fails because offset 32 is beyond the end of the `output_data` array.